# Java, my image will not update/move

Tags: java, image, swing, repaint, keylistener

I'm quite a newbie to Java stuff, but.. after reading a lot online, I've been trying to work on this game and getting started, I'm working with a few images. I'm trying to update their positions to demonstrate movement of course through `KeyListener`, I believe. unfortunately, the image remains in the same spot and refuses to move D:

I'm sure I overcomplicated some of this code, but here it is :\

```
public class Game extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    private Vladimir vlad;
    private Timer timer;

    public Game() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024,768));
        setDoubleBuffered(true);

        vlad = new Vladimir();
        timer = new Timer(15,this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
        repaint();
    }

    private void toggleKey(int keyCode, boolean pressed){
        if (keyCode == 87){ // W
             vlad.move("UP", pressed);
        }

        if (keyCode == 83){ // S
            vlad.move("DOWN", pressed);
        }

        if (keyCode == 65) // A
        {
            vlad.move("LEFT", pressed);
        }

        if (keyCode == 68) // D
        {
            vlad.move("RIGHT", pressed);
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        toggleKey(e.getKeyCode(), true);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        toggleKey(e.getKeyCode(), false);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.drawImage(vlad.getGrassMap(),0,0,this);
        g2d.drawImage(vlad.getCharOne(),vlad.getX(),vlad.getY(),this);

        repaint();


      }
}
```

And then..

```
public class Vladimir{

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Image grassMapOne;
    private Image charOne;
    private String gMapLocate = "/phantasma/resources/GrassMap1.png";
    private String charOneLocate = "/phantasma/resources/moveright1.png";

    public Vladimir(){
        ImageIcon gMap1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(gMapLocate));
        ImageIcon char1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(charOneLocate));
        grassMapOne = gMap1.getImage();
        charOne = char1.getImage();
        x = 512;
        y = 350;
    }

    public void move(String direction, boolean keyHeld){
        if (direction == "UP"){
            y += 12;
        }

        if (direction == "DOWN"){
            y -= 12;
        }

        if (direction == "LEFT"){
            x -= 12;
        }

        if (direction == "RIGHT"){
            x += 12;
        }
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public Image getGrassMap(){
        return grassMapOne;
    }

    public Image getCharOne(){
        return charOne;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use magic numbers (87, 83, 65, 68). The KeyEvent class has VK_UP etc.. variables which should be used.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5):

First you need to know what is wrong before you can fix it, so you should first ask yourself, not why the image isn't moving, but is the key listener even listening? If you add `println` statements like this one:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("in keyPressed. keyCode is: " + e.getKeyCode());
    toggleKey(e.getKeyCode(), true);
}
```

you'll see that it's not, that it requires a component that is able to receive focus and that actually has focus.

You will need to set the `JPanel`'s focusable property to true and then have it `acceptFocusInWindow()` after it has been rendered.

Better still -- use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), since they are much more flexible when it comes to focus issues, and are a higher-level construct. They are in fact what Swing itself uses to have components react to key presses.

Next, don't use `==` to compare `String`s as this only checks if two `String` objects are one and the same, something you don't care about. Instead you want to know if one `String` has the same characters in the same order as another `String`, and for this you want to use `String`'s `equals(...)` method or its `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps a great deal! Really appreciate it; I'll look into key bindings a bit later, but right now, the only thing I'm confused about in your entire post is the `acceptFocusInWindow()` part - not sure how or where I should be calling that or dealing with it at all? Thanks again!

Comment: You would call that on the listened-to component after the GUI has been rendered. Usually that's after either `pack()` or `setVisible(true)` has been called on the enclosing top-level window.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, but after adding in all of your changes, it still doesn't seem to work.. I guess key bindings it is then haha.

Comment: @user962797: hard to say. You may want to post your latest code here... but that will be for someone else to analyze -- I'm going to bed. Good night and good luck!